# Is it possible set custom headers when send strapi graphql request from client?

Tags: strapi

When I trying to send request to strapi and add custom headers like 'X-Favorite-Food' or  'Favorite-Food' strapi send me failed request error, so I wonder if it possible at all to say strapi server that we want to handle own header.

**Example:**

```
  headers: {
      authorization: Bearer ${AccessToken},
      'X-Favorite-Food': 'pizza',
```

So do we have some way to enable custom headers in strapi?